# Sorting a string based on prefixes

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, arrays

If you are given an array with random prefixes, like this:

```
DOG_BOB
CAT_ROB
DOG_DANNY
MOUSE_MICKEY
DOG_STEVE
HORSE_NEIGH
CAT_RUDE
HORSE_BOO
MOUSE_STUPID
```

How would i go about sorting this so that i have 4 different arrays/lists of strings?

So the end result would give me 4 string ARRAYS or lists with

```
DOG_BOB,DOG_DANNY,DOG_STEVE <-- Array 1
HORSE_NEIGH, HORSE_BOO <-- Array 2
MOUSE_MICKEY, MOUSE_STUPID <-- Array 3
CAT_RUDE, CAT_ROB <-- Array 4
```

sorry about the names i just made them up lol

```
var fieldNames = typeof(animals).GetFields()
                    .Select(field => field.Name)
                    .ToList();
List<string> cats = new List<string>();
List<string> dogs = new List<string>();
List<string> mice= new List<string>();
List<string> horse = new List<string>();
foreach (var n in fieldNames)
{
    var fieldValues = typeof(animals).GetField(n).GetValue(n);"

    //Here's what i'm trying to do, with if statements
    if (n.ToString().ToLower().Contains("horse"))
    {
    }
}
```

So i need them to be splitted into STRING ARRAYS/STRING LISTS and NOT just strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] strings = new string[] { 
                      "DOG_BOB",
                      "CAT_ROB",
                      "DOG_DANNY",
                      "MOUSE_MICKEY",
                      "DOG_STEVE",
                      "HORSE_NEIGH",
                      "CAT_RUDE",
                      "HORSE_BOO",
                      "MOUSE_STUPID"};

string[] results = strings.GroupBy(s => s.Split('_')[0])
                          .Select(g => String.Join(",",g))
                          .ToArray();
```

Or maybe something like this

```
List<List<string>> res = strings.ToLookup(s => s.Split('_')[0], s => s)
                                 .Select(g => g.ToList())
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: how do i get it in different strings? not just one array, i want 4 different string arrays, or lists.

Comment: @Ramie *results* is "4 strings" and every item in it contains the string you want. just loop over it.

Comment: i meant like 4 string array or 4 string lists categorized by prefix

Comment: @Ramie I Know. How about running the code and see what *results* contains. I  bet it is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
var groups = fieldNames.GroupBy(n => n.Split('_')[0]);
```

Usage

```
foreach(var group in groups)
{
    // group.Key (DOG, HORSE, CAT, etc)

    foreach(var name in group)
         // all names groped by prefix
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (String s in strings)
{
    if (s.StartsWith("CAT_")
        cats.Add(s);
    else if (s.StartsWith("HORSE_")
        horses.Add(s);
    // ...
}
```

Or:

```
foreach (String s in strings)
{ 
    String[] split = s.Split(new Char [] { '_' });

    if (split[0].Equals("CAT")
        cats.Add(s);
    else if (split[0].Equals("HORSE")
        horses.Add(s);

    // ...
}
```

But I would prefer the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmically, I'd do the following:

1. Parse out all unique prefixes by using the "_" as your delimeter.
2. Loop through your list of prefixes.
   2a. Retrieve any values that have your prefix (loop/find/regex/depends on structure)
   2b. Place retrieved values in a List.
   2c. Sort list.
3. Output your results, or do what you need with your collections.

Comment: The advantage of parsing out based off "_" is that you can use this with new prefixes at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ, using something like

```
names.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("_"))) // group by prefix
     .Select(g => string.Join(",", g))             // join each group with commas
     .ToList();                                    // take the results
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/KQBIBa)** (some extra `.ToArray()` calls included for .NET 3.0 compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

This LINQ expression does what you want.

```
var result = data.GroupBy(data.Split('_')[0])
                 .Select(group => String.Join(", ", group))
                 .ToList();
```

For a list of lists of strings use this expression.

```
var result = data.GroupBy(data.Split('_')[0])
                 .Select(group => group.ToList())
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: how do i get it in different strings? not just one array, i want 4 different string arrays, or lists.

Comment: Just omit `String.Join()` - updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can order the list up front and sort by prefix:

```
        string[] input = new string[] {"DOG_BOB","CAT_ROB","DOG_DANNY","MOUSE_MICKEY","DOG_STEVE","HORSE_NEIGH","CAT_RUDE","HORSE_BOO","MOUSE_STUPID"};
        string[] sortedInput = input.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
        var distinctSortedPrefixes = sortedInput.Select(item => item.Split('_')[0]).Distinct().ToArray();

        Dictionary<string, string[]> orderedByPrefix = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
        for (int prefixIndex = 0; prefixIndex < distinctSortedPrefixes.Length; prefixIndex++)
        {
            string prefix = distinctSortedPrefixes[prefixIndex];
            var group = input.Where(item => item.StartsWith(prefix)).ToArray();
            orderedByPrefix.Add(prefix, group);
        }
```